# Centering text with CSS not behaving right. Will not center

Tags: html, css

I've been fiddling with this for 2 days, and can't seem to get it right. So thought I would ask for a resolution here. (I'm not a css expert and that is where the problem lies.)

So I have the following code:

```
<table class="demo">
<tr>
<th style="background:#FFFFFF;border:0px solid #FFFFFF;" WIDTH="140">
        <img src="https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/images/genesys_logo_1.png" border="0"><BR><BR>
</th>
<th>
    <form method="post" action="https://xxxxxxxxxx.com<?php echo $thisPage; ?>" onsubmit="return mysubmit(this);">
    <input type="hidden" name="primary" value="<?php echo array_values($p_key)[$i]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="archived" value="y">
    <input style="float: left; display: block;margin: 42px 0px 0px -1px ;!important;" type="submit" VALUE="&#9988"/>
    </form>
        <span style="font-size: 16px; !important;"><?php if(array_values($link_kt)[$i]!="") {?><A href="<?php echo array_values($link_kt)[$i]; ?>" TARGET="_BLANK"><?php } ?><?php echo $cust_name[$i]; ?><?php if(array_values($link_kt)[$i]!="") {?></a><?php } ?></SPAN>
            <BR>
        <span style="font-size: 11px; text-align: middle; !important;">PID: <?php if(array_values($link_oa)[$i]!="") {?><A href="<?php echo array_values($link_oa)[$i]; ?>" TARGET="_BLANK"><?php } ?><?php echo array_values($pid)[$i]; ?><?php if(array_values($link_oa)[$i]!="") {?></a><?php } ?></span>
    <form action="<?php echo $linkUpdate; ?>" method="post">
    <input style="float: right; display: block;margin: 6px -1px 0px 0px ;!important;" type="submit" value="&#9998;&nbsp;" />
    </form>
</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

And the following css:

```
.demo {
    width:100%;
    border:0px solid #333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    border-spacing:0px;
    padding:3px;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
.demo th {
    min-width:160px;
    max-width:160px;

    border:1px solid #333333;
    padding:3px;
    background:#999999;

    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;

}
```

[image: Displays like this]

It displays the cell like this: Notice the 2 lines of text (in spans above) are NOT centered ... and it is driving me crazy !

I want everything to stay in place when resizing the screen. Right now the buttons are behaving perfectly but I cannot for the life of me get the text to stay centered.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the span that need to be centered

```
<span style="font-size: 16px; !important;"><?php if(array_values($link_kt)[$i]!="") {?><A href="<?php echo array_values($link_kt)[$i]; ?>" TARGET="_BLANK"><?php } ?><?php echo $cust_name[$i]; ?><?php if(array_values($link_kt)[$i]!="") {?></a><?php } ?></SPAN>
        <BR>
    <span style="font-size: 11px; text-align: middle; !important;">PID: <?php if(array_values($link_oa)[$i]!="") {?><A href="<?php echo array_values($link_oa)[$i]; ?>" TARGET="_BLANK"><?php } ?><?php echo array_values($pid)[$i]; ?><?php if(array_values($link_oa)[$i]!="") {?></a><?php } ?></span>
```

For making it centered give both the span a fixed width and margin:0 auto
For example if you want the width for the 1st span to be 1060px then in style add width and margin as:

```
<span style="font-size: 16px; width:1060px; margin:0 auto;"><?php if(array_values($link_kt)[$i]!="") {?><A href="<?php echo array_values($link_kt)[$i]; ?>" TARGET="_BLANK"><?php } ?><?php echo $cust_name[$i]; ?><?php if(array_values($link_kt)[$i]!="") {?></a><?php } ?></SPAN>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for:)

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: There was another comment here, but it is gone now ... it helped me solve the issue. It was as simple as adding this to my css: .demo th span {
  padding: 0px 16px 0px 0px;
} Problem resolved

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is, but two points which might help:

1.) It's `text-align: center` , not `text-align: middle`  like in your code (for horizontal centering)

2.) A `span` is an inline element. To center something inside a span therefore doesn't do anything. You have to center the span inside it's parent, so in this case the table cell around it has to have `text-align: center` (or in your case actually the `th` - maybe you should insert a `td` here in case that doesn't work)